# Нужна ли запятая?

Tags: пунктуация

В предложении "Так вот (?) что мне надо!" нужна ли запятая перед словом "что"?

Answer (score 3):

Запятая не нужна. Указательная частица *вот* запятой не отделяется.

Answer (score 1):

У Лопатина: 9. Запятая не ставится перед союзом что в выражении только и…что, за которым следует существительное или местоимение: Только и денег что пятак в кармане; Только и всего что рубашка на теле; Только и развлечений что кино раз в неделю; Только и свету что в окошке; Только и разговоров что о них двоих.
Приведенные словосочетания -- цельные, внутри них не ставится запятая. Так вот что - тоже цельное сочетание